фон на сайте как в Apple Music (градиент и блюр). css и js
может у кого-то есть темплейт... в общем в Apple Music фон берется из цветов обложки песни, а я хочу задавать такие цвета самостоятельно. но мне нужен именно код для фона страничек

background-image называется...можно и svg на фон поставить

Для этого нужно использовать css стили.


body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  
  background-color: rgba(10, 15, 20, 0.5); /* здесь устанавливается прозрачность фона и цвет */
  backdrop-filter: blur(20px) saturate(180%); /* как раз тот эффект размытия */
  background: linear-gradient(blue, pink); /* градиент */
}
<div class="container"></div>



Экспериментируйте с этими параметрами для достижения нужного результата.

И блур тут ничего не делает
